# How to pre-select radio group button when "name" attribute has "[]" brackets in it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

If I remove the `[` and `]` in the name attribute this script works. What am I doing wrong? I want to post array to the backend so I'm using array syntax in the HTML.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="a[1]" id="1" value="0"/>
<label for="1">option1</label>

<input type="radio" name="a[1]" id="2" value="1"/>
<label for="2">option2</label>

<input type="radio" name="a[1]" id="3" value="2"/>
<label for="3">option3</label>

<input type="radio" name="a[1]" id="4" value="3"/>
<label for="4">option4</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name=a[1]][value=" + 2 + "]").prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put attribute value (i.e `a[1]` in your case) in single quotes as shown below :

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='a[1]'][value=" + 2 + "]").prop('checked', true);
    });
 </script>
```

*From [the docs for attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)...*

> **attribute** An attribute name.
>
> **value** An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.

Since you have more than just a single word, it should be quoted.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfs8z8d2/)

Comment: Right now jquery Official website is down you can visit link given in answer after some time.

Comment: @user7031...i think above answer will solve your problem if need more help then plz comment.

Comment: Thank you very much,single quote should be used,that is the solution for this!

Comment: @user7031..yes that is what i have written in my answer...my answer is not clear..plz tell if is it so my english is not that good????

Comment: Well,your answer is clear enough to my question,it is a big help!